# How does "bitbake virtual/kernel" work if kernel recipes don't have PROVIDES variable set to virtual/kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to understand a few pieces associated with using bitbake to compile the linux image and generating a boot image that would be used to flash onto the processor.

- How come `bitbake virtual/kernel` really works? Read through [section 2.3](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) and it says recipes use `PROVIDES` parameter to add an extra provider, which indicates a recipe could be called in multiple ways (by its name, and by whatever `PROVIDES` is set to). But the kernel recipes (`../poky/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel`) I checked didn't have `PROVIDES` parameter let alone it being set to `virtual/kernel`.
- Upon running `bitbake virtual/kernel`, how come a `boot.img` is being generated when it should only just be generating a linux binary i.e `vmlinux` for instance?
  In one of the kernel `.inc` files, I see:

```
DEPENDS += " mkbootimg-native openssl-native kern-tools-native"
...
FILESPATH =+ "${WORKSPACE}:"
SRC_URI   =  "file://kernel \
              ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'systemd', 'file://systemd.cfg', '', d)} \
              ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'virtualization', 'file://virtualization.cfg', '', d)} \
              ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'nand-squashfs', 'file://squashfs.cfg', '', d)} \
```

`mkbootimg-native` I reckon refers to the boot image recipe that the kernel recipe depends on, though shouldn't it be the other way around since the boot image should contain the kernel image itself?

- lastly, is there a way to put debug prints in different recipe files to see if it's being invoked? I tried `echo`...to no avail

Answer (score 1):

The recipes you checked probably had `PROVIDES`. Most if not all kernel recipes `inherit kernel` class (directly or via some other classes, such as kernel-yocto). The kernel.bbclass actually specifies `PROVIDES` for you, c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/kernel.bbclass#n8).

`boot.img` does not seem to be created by default for any machine. After a quick glance at the code, it seems that this is created by `wic` for images inheriting the `image-live` bbclass or by adding `live` to `IMAGE_FSTYPES`, c.f. http://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#image-live-bbclass.
From a simple git grep in the poky git repo, it seems only `bootimg-efi.py` is actually doing something with a `boot.img` which is called by `wic` when the `-b` or `--bootimg-dir` argument is passed, which is enforced when using `wic`. So probably the `boot.img` artifact is created only for EFI machines and images.

If you use `echo` or `printf` or similar shell functions (or `print` in Python tasks) in your tasks, you can only see them in `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_<task>` of your recipe. Otherwise, you can use `bbplain`, `bbnote`, `bbdebug`, `bbwarn`, `bberror` or `bbfatal`. This will print to both the logs and the console (depending on your log level which is configurable with `-D` (the more Ds, the higher the log level)).

Comment: where's `kernel.bbclass` located? can't seem to find under `poky/meta-bsp/classes` and some other dirs.
And regarding `boot.img`, I did some digging and realized there's a task `do_make_bootimg` that's located in `log.do_listtasks` under kernel directory, which means every time I run `bitbake virtual/kernel1, `do_make_bootimg` gets called which ends up generating a boot image. As a follow-up, do you know what determines what tasks need to run upon compiling a specific image?

Comment: regarding print, `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_<task>` -> what's `task`? is it where I used `printf` or `echo`? Also, I did use `bbwarn` and others but it just gives our syntax errors

Comment: `kernel.bbclass` is in `openembedded-core/classes` or `poky/meta/classes` as the link I pasted suggests.
Yocto creates a tree of dependencies for tasks. When you request a task to be run, all its dependencies are run beforehand. When you run `bitbake my-recipe`, Yocto triggers the `build` task which has a majority of tasks in its dependency tree. When you add a recipe to `DEPENDS`, `do_populate_sysroot` of said package is triggered. Etc...

Comment: `task` is the name of the task in which you added your `echo` or `printf` statements. If you tried to use `bbwarn` and didn't manage to, maybe you could also ask for this? Take example from `bbwarn` uses in poky recipes and if you still can't find what's wrong, create a new post.

Comment: Right, I see that. So basically the kernel recipe inherits from the `kernel.bbclass` and the class uses `PROVIDES` parameter which is set to `virtual/kernel`, meaning the recipe could be called via `virtual/kernel`. It's just most of the things in the class seem pretty complex but i'm just trying to get a higher level understanding so I can make sense of the things...

Comment: a follow-up: do you see where the order and the type of tasks come from in `log.task_order` and `log.do_listtasks` respectively?

Comment: The task dependency tree is created by `addtask`, c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#tasks. They are defined all over the place so it won't probably be easy to find the location of each and every addtask that applies to your recipe (e.g. the `base.bbclass` is implicitly inherited by all recipes.

Comment: that means I should take that for granted cause I probably would only be integrating changes in the existing yocto instead of creating from scratch?

Comment: You can add your own tasks too and you need to do it if inheriting the `deploy` class for example. But yes, you probably don't need to know where and how most of the tasks are added by Yocto for your recipe. Though note that the order in which tasks are displayed in `log.task_order` can be non-deterministic (it's a tree after all with branches that can merge back into the tree later than others).

Comment: I see. Also, how come `inherit kernel` actually refers to inheriting from `kernel.bbclass`? is it implied by the yocto?

Comment: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#inherit-directive states that inherit directive only applies to classes (files ending with .bbclass in <layer-root>/classes/ directories). Therefore, .bbclass would be redundant.